# Remove subsequent duplicates items in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, duplicates

I have below a list.

```
['AAB', 'CAA', 'ADA', 'CADA', 'AACA']
```

and I am trying to get

```
['AB', 'CA', 'AD', 'CAD', 'AC']
```

Order of the out is important.

Comment: Have you tried something or ? Where are you stuck in your solution?

Comment: We won't write the code for you. First of all, try and work out what the function is that relates the two lists, then apply that function to each list item.

Comment: @RafaelC
I have tried using set but it didn't work. It is very important that only subsequent duplicate is removed and set doesn't do that.

Comment: @AriCooper-Davis
 I have tried using set but it didn't work. It is very important that only subsequent duplicate is removed and set doesn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the order of chars in output matters to you. you can use `OrderedDict` like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
a = ['AAB', 'CAA', 'ADA', 'CADA', 'AACA']
print(["".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(i)) for i in a])
# ['AB', 'CA', 'AD', 'CAD', 'AC']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Order of direct is important and therefore couldn't use sets.

Comment: @ArpitShah I deleted my second section of my answer. you can use `OrderedDict` solution I wrote in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Without an `OrderedDict` and using `set` and also maintain order to output.

```
x = ['AAB', 'CAA', 'ADA', 'CADA', 'AACA']
["".join([z.add(c) or c for c in w if c not in z]) for w, z in [(w, set()) for w in x]]
```

Output:

```
['AB', 'CA', 'AD', 'CAD', 'AC']
```

The list comprehension actually fills up a set for each word, so the complexity does not increase.